# How to implement console-like readline in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a console-looking html. I am trying to implement a readline function. I already tried using an input tag which returns the value in onchange but it doesn't work properly? How will I do a proper readline which obviously pauses the next lines, waits for a value, repeats if it is empty, and returns it in onchange and continues?

I have tried the following:

```
document.write('<input id="in" onchange="function(){ result = document.getElementById('in').value; /* because it has no return value */}"></input>
```

Comment: This might help-https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell#readline()

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have tried `document.write('<input id="in" onchange="function(){result = document.getElementById('in').value; /* because it has no return value */}"></input>`.

Comment: @Mamun it wont work in html.

Comment: You cannot (and should not) write a UI function that pauses. It needs to be asynchronous.